# build-helper-maven-plugin : attach-artifact doesn't copy artifact into repository

Tags: maven, artifacts

Do I need to add install-file and deploy-file to my pom after attaching an additional artifact?  I believe I added my artifact correctly, but maven seems to think the artifact is already in place even thought it's not there.

After adding my additional artifact to the pom via attach-artifact I see that maven attempts to copy the file and lists the file in local repo *maven-metadata-local.xml* but the file doesn't get copied because it seems unchanged.

FYI - This artifact is generated by assembly-plugin and if I remove the build-helper then maven doesn't even attempt to copy the artifact.

Please let me know if you have any ideas.

Thanks

Peter

*Debug Log*

```
[INFO] Installing ./trunkProject/modules/mymodule/target/dist/added-artifact-lin64-1.0.0.59258.tar.gz 
    to ./m2repo/corp/prod/modules/mymodule/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/added-artifact-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-dist.tar.gz
[DEBUG] Skipped re-installing ./trunkProject/modules/mymodule/target/dist/aie-module-mymodule-lin64-1.0.0.59258.tar.gz 
    to ./m2repo/corp/prod/modules/mymodule/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/added-artifact-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-dist.tar.gz, 
    seems unchanged
```

*Pom.xml*

```
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
        <executions>           
            <execution>             
                <id>attach-distribution-artifact</id>             
                <phase>package</phase>             
                <goals>               
                    <goal>attach-artifact</goal>             
                </goals>            
                <configuration>
                  <artifacts>
                    <artifact>
                      <file>${distTop}/${assemblyFinalName}-${real.os.full}-${prod.version}.${svn.revision}.tar.gz</file>
                      <type>tar.gz</type>
                      <classifier>dist</classifier>
                    </artifact>
                  </artifacts>
                </configuration>          
                </execution>         
        </executions>             
    </plugin>
```

*Assembly File*

```
<assembly>
  <id>dist</id>
  <formats>
    <format>${distCompressed.ext}</format>
  </formats>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <directory>${kitTop}</directory>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>**/Thumbs.db</exclude>
      </excludes>
      <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
```

Comment: No, you don't need to add `install-file` and `deploy-file`. The easiest way to check is to remove this artifact from your local repository and see if it gets there after your project has been built.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but it still reports the same problem.  I also tried starting with a new local maven repo

Comment: Try to remove `mymodule/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT` directory from repository completely and rebuild the project. The issue seems really strange. What version of maven are you using?

Comment: I'm using maven 3.0.3 and 1.7 of the attach plugin.   I also removed my entire m2repo local repo.  I also removed the mymodule/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT  In each case I get the same result.   The artifact is produced with the maven-assembly-plugin.  could this be part of the problem.  If assembly plugin didn't add it as an attachment and I add it with build-helper then I'm confusing maven?

Comment: Well, yes, this could be the problem. `assembly` plugin has `<attach>` conf option. Why don't you use it? I tend to use build helper when there is some artifact that is produced for example by ant or some other external tool.

Comment: The `<attach>` configuration is `true` by default: [`maven-assembly-plugin:single#attach`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/single-mojo.html#attach).

Comment: I tried adding the attach (although default is for assembly-plugin is attach).  I removed the helper plugin and maven no longer even attempts to copy the file when I build in debug.  I must have some other aspect of the build files blocking the attachment process

Comment: Show the assembly plugin conf.

Comment: Sure, here's the assembly file.   Because I use a custom file name I am seeing this warning:  [WARNING] Configuration options: 'appendAssemblyId' is set to false, and 'classifier' is missing.

Comment: Thanks for the help on this.  Please see the answer below

Comment: The normal phase for the assembly plugin is 'package' not verify.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19552/discussion-between-peter-kahn-and-maba)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was simple order of operations.  The assembly was generate during the install phase which meant the installer-plugin couldn't locate it.  I don't have evidence for how this got blocked build-helper but I suspect that assemble-plugin attached, installer-failed to install and recorded the item.  When build-help executed it may have been attempting to work which installer plugin already tried.

*Solution*

- Remove build-helper
- Change assembly plugin phase from install to *package* ensuring that the artifact exists prior to installation
- set appendAssemblyId to true in pom's maven-assembly-plugin configuration

Comment: The normal phase for the assembly plugin is 'package' not verify.

Comment: Ok, Is appendAssemblyId required because classifier was removed and therefore there is no other way to distinguish an assembly name from the main artifact?